# Expression statement is not assignment or call when looping through a list and trying to create a grid layout of components

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a grid layout of video components but my IDE gives me a warning saying

```
Expression statement is not assignment or call 


import React, {Fragment} from 'react';
import VideoClip from "../Video/VideoClip";



function SubjectView(props) {

    let ids = ["RfKHsvF69VdjdMu6bdugsyRcjYpQXrpKd6iZHeEknCkY00",
        "RfKHsvF69VdjdMu6bdugsyRcjYpQXrpKd2ipHeEknCkY00",
        "RfKHsvF69Vdjdiu6bdugsyRcjYpQXrpKd2iZHeEknCkY00"
    ];

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <div className="columns-3" >
                {ids.map((id)=>{
                    <VideoClip id={id}/>
                    console.log(id)
                })}
            </div>
        </Fragment>

    );
}

export default SubjectView;
```

I see the IDs printed in the console but nothing renders.

The video component looks like

```
function VideoClip() {

    let { id } = useParams();

    return (
        <div className="container mx-auto px-4">
            <MuxPlayer
                streamType="on-demand"
                playbackId={id}
                metadata={{
                    video_id: "video-id-54321",
                    video_title: "Test video title",
                    viewer_user_id: "user-id-007",
                }}
            />
        </div>
    );

}

export default VideoClip
```

I am wondering if I am trying to create the components incorrectly. Is there a best practice when trying to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue is you are not returning `<VideoClip id={id}/>` in map function in jsx. Also, if map is used - `key` needs to be set

```
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className="columns-3">
        {ids.map((id) => {
          console.log(id);
          return <VideoClip key={id} id={id} />;
        })}
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
```

Next issue is about VideoClip component parameter. Id needs to be extracted in that way in case it is passed as an attribute. Also, memoize the objects that you are passing down to a components. Metadata here, for example.

```
function VideoClip({ id }) {
  const metadata = useMemo(() => {
    return {
      video_id: "video-id-54321",
      video_title: "Test video title",
      viewer_user_id: "user-id-007"
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="container mx-auto px-4">
      <MuxPlayer streamType="on-demand" playbackId={id} metadata={metadata} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Last thing - wrap your array in useMemo so this array will not cause crazy rerenders.

```
  const ids = useMemo(
    () => [
      "RfKHsvF69VdjdMu6bdugsyRcjYpQXrpKd6iZHeEknCkY00",
      "RfKHsvF69VdjdMu6bdugsyRcjYpQXrpKd2ipHeEknCkY00",
      "RfKHsvF69Vdjdiu6bdugsyRcjYpQXrpKd2iZHeEknCkY00"
    ],
    []
  );
```

[image: Edit ecstatic-bohr-wc93oq]

Note: you will see x2 logs in the console in the Codesandbox due to `<StrictMode>` is set.

Answer (score 1):

You're not returning any value from `ids.map`

```
<>
    <div className="columns-3" >
        {ids.map((id)=><VideoClip id={id}/>)}
    </div>
</>
```